# How to compute "binary values addition of characters" for checksum

Tags: java

Working in Java, here is the specification i have in order to implement a checksum calculation on character messages:

```
    8.3.3 Checksum—The checksum permits the receiver to detect a defective frame. The checksum is encoded as two characters which are sent after the <ETB> or <ETX> character. The checksum is computed by adding the  binary values of the characters, keeping the least significant eight bits of the result.
    8.3.3.1 The checksum is initialized to zero with the <STX> character. The first character used in computing the checksum is the frame number. Each character in the message text is added to the checksum (modulo 256). The computation for the checksum does not include <STX>, the checksum characters, or the trailing <CR> and <LF>.
    8.3.3.2 The checksum is an integer represented by eight bits, it can be considered as two groups of four bits. The groups of four bits are converted to the ASCII characters of the hexadecimal representation. The two ASCII characters are transmitted as the checksum, with the most significant character first.
    8.3.3.3 For example, a checksum of 122 can be represented as 01111010 in binary or 7A in hexadecimal. The checksum is transmitted as the ASCII character 7 followed by the character A.
```

Here is what i have understand and implemented, but it doesn't seem to be working... :

```
    private void computeAndAddChecksum(byte[] bytes, OutputStream outputStream) {
    logBytesAsBinary(bytes);
    long checksum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        checksum += (bytes[i] & 0xffffffffL);
            }
            int integerChecksum = (int)checksum;
    String hexChecksum = Integer.toHexString(integerChecksum).toUpperCase();
    logger.info("Checksum for "+new String(bytes)+" is "+checksum+" in hexa: "+hexChecksum);
    try {
        if (outputStream != null)
        {
            outputStream.write(hexChecksum.getBytes());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Do you any idea why this snippet is not adapted to the specification ?
Here is an example i was given if it could help:

```
    <STX>3L|1<CR><ETX>3C<CR><LF>
```

so the checksum of

```
    3L|1<CR><ETX>
```

should be

```
    3C
```

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working" - what *exactly* do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your specification says:

- the checksum should be initialized with frame number.

Here is a snippet that returns the expected result, but i don't know where frame number comes from (surey elsewhere in your spec)

```
public class ChecksumBuilder {
public static String getFrameCheckSum(String frametext,int framenum)
{
    byte[] a=frametext.getBytes();

    int checksum=framenum;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {           
        checksum+=a[i];
    }

    String out=String.format("%02x",(checksum & 0xFF)).toUpperCase();
    return out;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.print(ChecksumBuilder.getFrameCheckSum("3L|1<CR>",1));
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Anyway, i've just realized the spec had been not formatted correctly because of not putting it into a code block. I modified the post so it is now OK. And you'll see the meaning may not be the one you understood reading it first time... sorry : my fault! And the frame number is the first "3" character in my message, just to tell that the checksum computation must start from there. thanks again

Comment: Well yes thanks for your help, but it does not answer the question really. Your code is quite similar to mine, and does not respect the specification. but ok, i give you a vote for your kindness ;)